# Scalar_Variable Function with Multiple AND statements returning "NULL"

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, ssis

Im writing Scalar-Variable function in sql to return a strName mapped by an integer.  The following is my script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Lookup_BSource_Value] 
(
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @AVal nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
      -- Declare the return variable here
      DECLARE @Val nvarchar(100)
      SELECT @Val = Val

      FROM SMBase
      WHERE AName = 'a_source'
      AND (OTypeCode = 1084)
      AND (AVal = (@AVal))

      RETURN @Val
END
```

I should be getting the result of "BA" but am receiving a "NULL".  Is my syntax correct for the multiple AND statements?

***EDIT****

Before use the function in my SSIS package I am just doing a simple 
    SELECT dbo.Lookup_BSource_Value(XXXXXXXXX)

This gives me the null.

The following is the logical schema of the table I am querying:

```
USE [MSCRM_M_RC]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SMBase]    Script Date: 1/21/2014 6:29:48 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SMBase](
    [OTypeCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AVal] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LaId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrgId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Val] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [DOrder] [int] NULL,
    [VNumber] [timestamp] NULL,
    [SMId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [cndx_PrimaryKey_SMap] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SMId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_SMap] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [OTCode] ASC,
    [AName] ASC,
    [AValue] ASC,
    [LaId] ASC,
    [OrgId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SMBase] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SMa_SMId]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [SMId]
GO
```

****EDIT*****

The following is my logical schema of my StringMapTable:

```
StringMap(SMID pk, OTypeCode,AName, AVal, LaID, OrgID fk, Val, DOrder, VNumber)
```

The following is my logical schema of my TPTRepair Table:

```
TPTRepair(TPTRepairID pk, Name, Source, TT, LTHrs, CustID fk, PID fk)
```

The problem is the following:

The "Source" field is an integer in TPTRepair.  I'm writing the following scalar-function to reference StringMap to return the string value from Value column in StringMap.  I have to have a couple ands because AName hase to = 'a_source' and OTypeCode has to = 1084.

My scalar-function results in a NULL and shouldn't be.  Is my syntax correct from the multiple AND statement in my scalar-function above?

Comment: Can you show the schema of the underlying table, some sample data, and how exactly you are calling the function?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have edited the original question for the content you requested

Comment: Some sample data would be good, as well as the ***actual syntax*** you're using, not `(XXXXXXXX)`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have posted the additional info that you requested.  Sorry it took a while.  I left work yesterday and just returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Im apparently an idiot.  It was the most simplest thing.  `OTypeCode` was to `= '10084'` rather than `'1084'`. Im an intern.  Please forgive me ;)  This was the answer.